# How do I overwrite inputfields with parsed value?

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, input

I'm trying to limit the set of characters allowed in an inputfield of number type. The problem is that I can't find a way to "overwrite" the text in the inputfield to delete not valid characters.

Here is the code Im testing with:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <input @input="validate" :model="message" placeholder="edit me">
    <p>Message is: {{ message }}</p>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    data: () => ({
      message: ""
    }),
    methods: {
      validate(input){
        // the regex is allowing only numbers and either a comma or a period
        this.message = input.target.value.match(/[0-9]*(,|\.)?[0-9]*/gm)[0]
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

All characters in the inputfield stays the same, while the "message" variable is the parsed validated string. How do I get that "message" string into the inputfield?

Edit: here is a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/p9s38rue/3/) of the code above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, `:model` is a shorthand for `v-bind:model` not to be confused with `v-model` for Vue directive (we want this one). So do this:

```vue
<input @input="validate" v-model="message" placeholder="edit me">
```

However, I would suggest using [Vue-Masked-Input](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-masked-input) component or [vue-inputmask](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vuejs-inputmask) (my personal preference) for this purpose, as they help with the input by ensuring a **predefined format**. This can be useful for dates, numerics, phone numbers, etc.

Answer (score 1):

There is a method in vuejs called watch that allows you to watch for DOM changes. Also :model is not the shorthand for v-model.

```
:model = v-bind:model
```

Here is a jsfiddle to a working example.
https://jsfiddle.net/awk7g2un/

Just replace my data with your parsed value